# IQueryable cannot implicity convert type using .single or .first

Tags: angularjs, iqueryable

```
    public IQueryable<Project> GetProjectPID(int projectid)
    {
        return _ctx.Projects.Include("TenNineHours").Where(r => r.ProjectId == projectid).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I am trying to get a single result here so I do not have to use ng-repeat for the base single object Project should return. I have tried it without the .Include as well. Or should I just filter the result in the controller.  Have made some effort there without results. Error is Cannot implicitly convert type 'TenNineAPP.Data.Project' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. An Explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)? New to Linq! Still working on this. Thanks,

Comment: If you are expecting `GetProjectPID` to return a single `Project` then why are you telling the compiler it returns an `IQueryable<Project>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are attempting to return an IQueryable of Project. Just return the single Project object;

```
public Project GetProjectPID(int projectid)
{
        return _ctx.Projects.Include("TenNineHours")
            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.ProjectId == projectid);
}
```